# running 2 clients at same time and getting stucked at 95% circuit_create: Establishing a Tor circuit after couple of minutes

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, torsocks

im running the expert tor.exe client (tor1 and tor2 at the same time) within a python script and selenium module.
the 2 tor.exe clients are getting killed after every run to get a new ip.
first runs are working, im getting 2 new ips every time, but after couple of minutes the tor.exe clients stuck at 95%. First i thought it is that im being blocked by Tor for too many requests but after reading thats not it.

i've restarted my PC and synched the windows time but still the same issue.
using a bridge would work but thats too slow.
after like 2 hours its working again.

but the tor browser is working! I think its something with my torrc file, do i need to add something?
this is my torrc file

```
SocksPort 9152
ControlPort 9052
CookieAuthentication 1
DataDirectory C:\Users\admin\Desktop\all\expert\torexpert\Tor2
```

you have any idea why its not working?

```
[notice] Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): > Establishing a Tor circuit
```

this is the netstat for port 9152

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         0.0.0.0:0              ABH?REN         15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         127.0.0.1:57668        HERGESTELLT     15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         127.0.0.1:57669        HERGESTELLT     15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         127.0.0.1:57670        HERGESTELLT     15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         127.0.0.1:57672        HERGESTELLT     15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         127.0.0.1:57673        HERGESTELLT     15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         127.0.0.1:57674        HERGESTELLT     15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         127.0.0.1:57675        HERGESTELLT     15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         127.0.0.1:57678        HERGESTELLT     15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         127.0.0.1:57679        HERGESTELLT     15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9152         127.0.0.1:57680        HERGESTELLT     15080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57667        127.0.0.1:9152         WARTEND         0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57668        127.0.0.1:9152         HERGESTELLT     7816
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57669        127.0.0.1:9152         HERGESTELLT     7816
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57670        127.0.0.1:9152         HERGESTELLT     7816
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57671        127.0.0.1:9152         WARTEND         0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57672        127.0.0.1:9152         HERGESTELLT     7816
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57673        127.0.0.1:9152         HERGESTELLT     7816
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57674        127.0.0.1:9152         HERGESTELLT     7816
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57675        127.0.0.1:9152         HERGESTELLT     7816
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57678        127.0.0.1:9152         HERGESTELLT     7816
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57679        127.0.0.1:9152         HERGESTELLT     7816
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57680        127.0.0.1:9152         HERGESTELLT     7816
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can control tor via the control port and request a new identity.
2. You can configure via the torrc.
   Values to check are:

   - NewCircuitPeriod
   - MaxCircuitDirtiness
   - NewCircuitPeriod

But in any way, new circuits not necessarily give you a new exit node, and so, not a new IP.

Also, rotating so often can make your more distinguishable and so, identifiable.

The defaults are there for a reason.